# ask confirmation before submiting form on multiple forms using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I've been browsing without much luck here, i have mutiple forms (deppending on the amount of records) that i want to ask confirmation prior to submiting the form.

code:

```js
    $(function() {
        $(".delete_button").click(function(){
            if (confirm("Click OK to continue?")){
                $('form').submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
    {% for blog in blogs %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{blog.getTitle}}</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{blog.getCreatedAt|date("j - n - Y, g:i a")}}</td><!--("F j, Y, g:i a")-->
        <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">{% trans %}table_actions_text{% endtrans %} <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>{% trans %}edit_text{% endtrans %}</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="form-group"><form id="whateverid" class="form-inline" method="post" action="{{path('deleteBlogPost')}}"><button <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete_button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <input name="id" id="id" type="hidden" value="{{blog.getId}}">{% trans %}delete_text{% endtrans %}</button></form></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

how do i make sure, that it submits its current form, and not any of the other forms?

Comment: give each form a different id. the delete click function know about said id and selects the correct form to submit

Comment: ID's *must* be unique and it looks like all of your buttons are `#delete_button`

Comment: forget about the id, thats the least important part of the question. the id can be changed anytime, it could easily be a class, all i want is to make sure that the delete button submits only its parent form, not any others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the parent form element of your delete button and submit that

```
$(this).closest("form").submit();
```

Comment: thank you! i was going through query api docs https://api.jquery.com/closest/ when checked back to the question ;)